# Can I install ALL required rpm to run wine without root permission?

Tags: rhel, package-management, rpm, wine

I am logged in on a redhat linux computer, and I don't have root permissions. I have tried running/installing wine on a folder using    `./configure`    , which outputs:

> configure: error: X 32-bit development files not found. Wine will be built
>   without X support, which probably isn't what you want. You will need
>   to install 32-bit development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 at the very
>   least. Use the --without-x option if you really want this.

Can I download and install ALL the packages required to install wine manually? ( I tried installing a few rpm packages, and it seemed like it worked.)

And if so, where do I find the full list of rpm's I need for `wine`?

Comment: Welcome to U&L, please read the [help tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain you how rpm files work and why you will not be able to install them without a lots of cheating.

`rpm` files are archives that deploys lib, binaries and conf files in the standard RHEL file hierarchy.
Problem is most path to those folders will not be user writable `/lib`, `/bin` or `/etc`.

If you need to install `wine` you will need to install all requested dependencies and binary in a subfolder where you wan write and change your root to this folder with the command `chroot` (almost impossible).

This exercise is complex and it's very unlikely someone without experience would succeed in such an experiment. By the way, if you're not admin, there's probably a reason and if you ask your sysadmin to install `wine` and he refuses, there's major chances that even if you succeed installing `wine`, your sysadmin would be very upset.